# Java - Trying to establish a connection with a remote SQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL database that I can access via web through http://smart.ihu.edu.gr/phpmyadmin/. The database inside that is `awesomedb/pwndoes'`. That's where the tables that I want to use are.

The thing is, I'm completely new to Database/mySQL connectivity in applications and even though I've tried working through the examples posted here: [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql) I've been unable to connect to the DB yet.

Here's my code:

```
package thesistest;

import java.sql.*;


public class ThesisTest {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    //-------------------------------------
    //  JDBC driver initialisation
    //-------------------------------------
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Loading driver...");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    }

    //-------------------------------------
    //  Driver loaded, let's try establishing a connection.
    //-------------------------------------
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://smart.ihu.edu.gr/phpmyadmin/awesomedb/pwnodes";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "[redacted]";
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Connecting database...");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }

}   //end of main

}   //end of class ThesisTest
```

I'm convinced that the URL I'm typing in is wrong.
**Note that the database is remote and I do not have an instance of any mySQL software running on my machine**. Is it possible to just connect a simple java app with a remote DB this way?

**Note 2:** I have tried putting :3306 at the end of the smart.ihu.edu.gr link, to no avail. Thanks for the headsup, @NickJ

By the way, here's the result of the build+run:

[image: results]

(Full resolution here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/etHVv.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java returns `Unknown Database` because it´s searching for a database on `/awesomedb/pwnodes` but the path you give is a table.
You have to give Java the path to your `awesomedb` and connect to it.
After that you send something like:

```
INSERT INTO pwnodes (col_name,...)
```

Code for connecting:

```
package theistest;


import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

   public class ThesisTest {

 public static void main(String[] argv) {

System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
Connection connection = null;

try {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://smart.ihu.edu.gr:3306/awesomedb";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "[redacted]";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

if (connection != null) {
    System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your insight, combined with Andrei Nicusan's answer down there was the correct answer.

With `String url = "jdbc:mysql://smart.ihu.edu.gr/awesomedb";` I managed to connect.

Thank you both, a lot.

Comment: Please edit out /phpmyadmin/ so that the url String looks like the above comment, so I can choose your answer as the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to go to `phpmyadmin` URL path.
My assumption is that MySQL runs on port 3306 on that server, but you don't need to reach `phpmyadmin`.

So I'd try the following URL: `jdbc:mysql://smart.ihu.edu.gr:3306/awesomedb/pwnodes`

Comment: It certainly cut down on the number of errors, but the connection still failed.

Here's the build results, if you're interested: http://i.imgur.com/pgDbZKk.png

Comment: you're missing the leading "j" in the URL

Comment: Yeah, came here to say just that. Even with jdbc:mysql://link restored, it still complains about `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'awesomedb/pwnodes'`

Comment: Here are the rules for building a MySQL JDBC URL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html . Are you sure the DB name is correct?

Comment: The URL was pointing to a table instead of the actual db. Look at Schlenderman's answer. Combined with yours it gave me the solution ;)